# If $\vec{v}$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $\vec{v} = \textbf{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I'm preparing for a test and was wondering if someone could validate my solution to the following problem:

> If $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $\vec{v} = \textbf{0}$.

I took the following approach.

---

$I.$ If $\vec{v}$ is orthogonal to all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it must be orthogonal to itself. Then $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}=v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2=0$, where $v_i$ is the $i$th component of $\vec{v}$.

$II$. $||\vec{v}||=\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2} = \sqrt{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}= \sqrt{0}=0.$ Then $\vec{v}$ has length $0$.

$III$. The vector of length $0$ is by definition the zero vector. Then $\vec{v}= \textbf{0}$.

---

As you can see, a pretty simple problem, but with the test ahead I want to leave no place for doubt. Thanks in advance. Oh, and by the way, alternative proofs are appreciated!

Comment: Your proof is fine. However, note that from $v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2 = 0$ you can immediately conclude $v_1=v_2=v_3=0$, since $v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2$ is the sum of three nonnegative quantities.

Comment: Another approach: Orthogonality of $v$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ implies $v_1=0$. Using the other standard basis vectors you can similarly show $v_2=0$ and $v_3=0$.

Comment: Nice proof! I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @angryavian That is true, thanks for pointing it out. And your alternative approach is also quite neat.

Comment: Thanks @N8tron!